# How to specify the install dir of libphp.so when compile php from source

Tags: php, apache

I'm new to PHP.Now i want to compile php5.5 from source and generate libphp5.so file in specify path on OS X.

My configure command

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php5.6.2/ --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --libexecdir=/usr/local/php5.6.2/libexec
```

But the command only install php to /usr/local/php5.6.2/ and install libphp.so to /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so.

How do i write the configure command?

Comment: What is the problem with the default ? Usually you need to set PREFIX

Comment: The default path is /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so.